# SELECT from two same table with intersect

Tags: sql, mysql, intersection, mysql-error-1064

The query:

```
SELECT id_user 
  FROM Rating 
 Where id_movie=2 
INTERSECT 
SELECT id_user 
  FROM Rating 
 Where id_movie=3
```

but I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT `id_user` FROM Rating Where `id_movie`=3 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

any have solution??

Comment: The error is because MySQL doesn't support the `INTERSECT` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

Following query will do ..

```
SELECT id_user 
FROM Rating 
Where id_movie=2 and id_user in 
             ( SELECT id_user FROM Rating Where id_movie=3);
```

Comment: You should be careful about NULLs with this syntax.

Comment: Depending on each subquery result size and order (`A and id_user in B` or `B and id_user in A`), mysql server can take a _really_ long time to give you a result.

Comment: This will not work for most of the cases because you don't know which id_movie should be in your subquery.

Answer (score 4):

Intersect, Minus keywords are absent in MySql and the workarounds are

1. Inner Join, and
2. Subqueries or
3. Left Join respectively.

Please look into here

[Doing INTERSECT and MINUS in MySQL](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71)

I have given a shot (though I am a SQL Server guy)

**Input:**

```
id_user id_movie
101 1
102 2
102 3
104 4
102 5
107 6
102 2
103 3
109 9
110 2
110 3
```

The output by using an intersect (if run in SQL Server) will be

```
id_user
102
110
```

MySQL compatible queries

**Query 1** using `Inner join`

```
select distinct a.id_user
from Rating a
join Rating b on a.id_user = b.id_user
where a.id_movie  = 2 and b.id_movie  = 3
```

**Query 2** using `Cross join`

```
select distinct a.id_user 
from Rating a, Rating b 
where a.id_user  = b.id_user 
  and a.id_movie  = 2
  and b.id_movie = 3
```

**Query 3** using subquery

Already answered above.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT r2.id_user
FROM Rating AS r2
   JOIN
   Rating AS r3
   ON r3.id_user = r2.id_user
   AND r2.id_movie=2
   AND r3.id_movie=3;
```

The idea here is that you want to join a row in Rating with another row in Rating, for which the same user has seen movies 2 and 3.