# Alternative for using Intersect operator in my sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, intersection

I have 2 tables with many to many cardinality between them. So by normalization I have created this :

```
   User
   UserId  UserName ....
     1       a
     2       b

  UserObject
  UserId  ObjectId
     1        1
     1        2
     2        2

  Object
  ObjectId  ObjectName
     1        c
     2        d
```

Now I want to run a query where I want to know users which have certain objects.

For example : All the users who have both objects c and d.

One way of doing it

```
   Select userid from UserObject where objectid=1 intersect Select userid from UserObject where objectid= 2
```

According to my use case, I may need to search for users having combination of 2-7 objects. It will not be prudent to write so many intersections.

I am working on postgesql 9.1.

What are the other efficient possible ways to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT uo.UserId
    FROM UserObject uo
    WHERE uo.ObjectId IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY uo.UserId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uo.ObjectId) = 2
```

Extending this concept for 7 objects:

```
SELECT uo.UserId
    FROM UserObject uo
    WHERE uo.ObjectId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    GROUP BY uo.UserId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uo.ObjectId) = 7
```

Comment: thnx :)
Can we do this using joins also?

Comment: @codecool: Sure. Can you provide additional details on what you'd want to join?

Comment: I was talking about something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878255/select-from-two-same-table-with-intersect/1878315#1878315
But my use case will require 7 joins to do this way which will not be efficient right?

Comment: @codecool: Yes, I would not take that approach for your particular case.

Comment: @codecool: If you have a **unique** constraint (or primary key) in place on `(user_id, object_id)`, which is common in such a scenario, you can skip the `DISTINCT`. Also, identifiers in PostgreSQL are case insensitive as long as you don't double quote them. My personal advice is to stay away from mixed case identifiers.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thnx for the comment. Yeah I will stay away from mixed case identifiers.